How badly does the geodesic exponential map fail to be $C^2$ on Finsler manifolds
Consider a Finsler manifold $M$. Then for each $x \in M$, we can consider the partial map $\exp_x: T_x M \to M$, which is $C^\infty$ away from the origin, $C^1$ at the origin, but never $C^2$ at the origin for all $x \in M$ unless $M$ is a Berwald space, in which case $\exp_x$ will actually be $C^\infty$.
Are there any results that control how badly $\exp_x$ fails to be $C^2$ at the origin for a Finsler manifold that is not a Berwald space. For instance, in some smooth coordinate system defined in a neighborhood of $x$, do we have bounds on the partial derivatives $(\partial_i \partial_j \exp_x^k)(v)$ as $v \to 0$? Perhaps a bound of the form
$$|(\partial_i \partial_j \exp_x^k)(v)| \leq C |v|^{-N} \quad\text{as $v \to 0$} $$
for some $N > 0$, and some constant $C > 0$ possibly depending on $x$?
Edit: For those unfamiliar with Finsler manifolds, the exponential map $\exp_x$ is the unique map with the property that for each $v \in T_x M$, the curve $c(t) = \exp_x(tv)$ is the unique constant speed geodesic on $M$ with $c(0) = x$ and $c'(0) = v$, i.e. an extremal for the length functional $L(c) = \int F(c,\dot{c})$, or equivalently, a (necessarily smooth) curve which in coordinates satisfies
the geodesic equation
$$ \ddot{c}^i + \dot{c}^j \dot{c}^k\ \gamma^i_{jk}(c, \dot{c}) = 0, $$
where $\dot{c} = \frac{dc}{dt}$, $\ddot{c} = \frac{d^2c}{dt^2}$,
$$ \gamma^i_{jk} = \frac{g^{is}}{2} \left( \frac{\partial g_{sj}}{\partial x^k} - \frac{\partial g_{jk}}{\partial x^s} + \frac{\partial g_{ks}}{\partial x_j} \right), $$
the metric coefficients $g_{ij}$ and their inverses $g^{ij}$ are defined by
$$ g_{ij} = \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2 F^2}{\partial v^i \partial v^j} $$
and Einstein notation is used throughout.

What is the definition of $\exp_x$ in this context? Can you give a reference for the facts you listed?

Specifically, I'm wondering how this fits with results I've heard reference to on an exponential map for the Teichmuller metric not being C^1. It seems likely not the same map as the one you are referring to. See Theorem 1.1 of the paper Teichmüller Distance is not C2+ε by Mary Rees: https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1112/S0024611503014369

Hey Alex - Thanks for your comment I've edited the post to clarify the definition of the exponential map. You can find proofs of these properties in Chapter 5, Section 3 of (Bao, Chern, Shen, An Introduction to Riemann-Finsler Geometry).

I believe what you're referring to could be related. The Teichmüller metric on a Teichmüller space seems to be an example of a Finsler metric (if the Teichmüller distance you're referring to is the same as from this paper: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0723086913000832 - it seems that there are several metrics that are used in the study of Teichmüller spaces, Teichmüller's 'classical metric' and Thurston's 'asymmetric metric' are both Finsler metrics).

The map Rees uses is basically the same, except that she defines it using the cotangent space rather than the tangent space. For the Teichmuller metric this is extremely natural for specific reasons, but in general terms one can comment that the Teichmuller norm is strictly convex, so there is a (non-linear) correspondence between directions in the tangent space and directions in the cotangent space.

So just to confirm, exp is just not defined in directions where there are multiple geodesics?

If you pick a point and a direction, there's always a unique geodesic starting at that point and travelling in that direction. It follows from the existence and uniqueness of ODEs for the geodesic equation above. Thus $exp_x$ is well defined on a neighborhood of the origin. But $exp_x$ it fails to be defined if your geodesics run into 'holes' in your manifold, i.e. if your manifold isn't complete.

Is the definition of a geodesic not a length minimizing path? With that definition, geodesics already aren't unique for R^2 with the supnorm Finsler metric. (For a more complicated example, I think they're also not unique for the asymmetric metric on Teichmuller space.)

I guess the issue is smoothness of the norm? In Hubbard, a standard book on Teichmuller theory that proves the Teichmuller metric is Finsler, the definition of a Finsler metric doesn't include any smoothness requirement. But the text you gave requires the norm to be smooth on the complement of the zero section.

Yes in the context I am dealing with the Finsler metric is assumed to be smooth and strictly convex. The sup norm would fail the strict convexity condition too.

Note:  I am making the standard assumptions in Finsler geometry, i.e., that $F:TM\to\mathbb{R}$ is smooth away from the zero section and $F$ is 'strictly convex'.
Although $\partial_i\partial_j\exp^k_p(v)$ is usually not continuous at $v=0$, there is a bound
$$
|\partial_i\partial_j\exp^k_p(v)|\le C(p),
$$
where $C(p)$ depends on $p\in M$.  Thus, one can take $N=0$ in the above desired bound.
To see this, for simplicity, take coordinates centered at $p$, and identify $M$ with a neighborhood of $0$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Let $\Sigma\subset T_0\mathbb{R}^n$ denote
the Finsler unit sphere (i.e., $F(u)=1$ for $u\in \Sigma$) and use `polar coordinates', then there exists a smooth map $E:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\times\Sigma\to\mathbb{R}^n$ so that the Finsler exponential map satisfies
$$
\exp_0(ru) = ru + r^2 E(r,u)
$$
for $u\in\Sigma$ and $r\ge0$.  (In fact, for each $u\in\Sigma$, the curve $\gamma_u(t) = tu + t^2 E(t,u)$ is a smooth geodesic for $|t|<\epsilon$.)  However, $E(r,u)$ for $0<r<\epsilon$, while it does define a bounded smooth function $E^*$ on a punctured neighborhood of $0\in\mathbb{R}^n$ (after shrinking $\epsilon$ if necessary), that function does not (usually) extend continuously to $0$, since $E(0,u):\Sigma\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is not usually constant.
Consider the 'polar coordinates' map $P:\mathbb{R}^+\times\Sigma\to\mathbb{R}^n$ given by
$P(r,u)=ru$.  This is a diffeomorphism onto $\mathbb{R}^n$ minus the origin.
Using this to identify the two spaces, we can express the vector fields $\partial_i$ as vector fields on
$\mathbb{R}^+\times \Sigma$:  We have
$$
\partial_i = p_i\,\partial_r + r^{-1} X_i
$$
where the $p_i$ are the smooth functions on $\Sigma$
satisfying $p_i\,\mathrm{d}u^i = 0$ and $p_iu^i=1$ (note the use of the summation convention)
and where the $X_i$ are the smooth vector fields on $\Sigma$
that satisfy $X_i(u^j)= \delta_i^j-u^jp_i$.  Via this identification, it follows that
$$
\partial_i\partial_j(r^2 E^*) 
= (p_i\,\partial_r + r^{-1} X_i)(p_j\,\partial_r + r^{-1} X_j) \bigl(r^2 E(r,u)\bigr).
$$
The latter expression is then seen to be a smooth function
on $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\times \Sigma$ and hence is bounded
(after one shrinks $\epsilon$ a little bit, if necessary).
However, there is no reason to believe that this function will be constant on the slice $r=0$
(and, indeed, in general it is not), so this function does not generally push forward under $P$
to extend to a continuous function on a neighborhood of $0\in\mathbb{R}^n$ (which, of course,
is why the exponential map is not $C^2$ at the origin in general).
